# GraphQL types: graphqlid or string for referenced objects?

Tags: mongodb, facebook-graph-api, mongoose, graphql, graphql-js

In my GraphQL application, there is a mongo collection with reference to other mongo/mongoose objects:

```
export const SingerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Singer",
    description: "A band´s singer",
    fields: () => ({
        id: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
        },
        name: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
        },
        band: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(BandType),
            resolve: (source, args, context) => {
                return Band.findOne({
                    _id: source.band_id
                }).exec();
            }
        }
        albuns: {
            type: new GraphQLList(AlbumType),
            resolve: (source, args, context) => {
                return Album.find({
                    _id: source._id
                }).exec();
            }
        }
    })
});

export const SingerInputType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
    name: "SingerInput",
    description: "Band´s singer input type",
    fields: () => ({
        name: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
        },
        band_id: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) <<== GraphQLString or GraphQLID here ???
        },
        albuns: {
            type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString) <<== GraphQLString or GraphQLID here ???
        }       }
    })
});
```

My doubt is:

Should I use `GraphQLString` or `GraphQLID` to reference other objects - individually or in arrays - as commented in the example code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use GraphQLString or GraphQLID to reference other objects individually, JOINS in mongodb is not cheap, it leads to very slow query because it queries the collections individually and aggregate then filter the result. This concept is not scalable. on like Relational Database that JOIN it is cheap.

1. My take is, if the data that will be stored in band and albuns are not large go with array option you can retrieve your result faster.
2. But if the values that will be stored in band and albuns is large and you are designing you app to scale, i will advise you use GraphQLID to reference band and albuns in another collection then use populate to load the content.

Check out this for more
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/

Comment: I responded based on how I understand the question. May be u try to be more explicit in your question